# Cannot pass quoted string as parameter to javadoc

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to make a simple script to generate the javadocs from my java sources.
Here is the script code:

```
#!/bin/sh
WINDOWTITLE='My Fancy Documentation'
DOCTITLE='Generator<sup><font size="-2">TM</font></sup> Productions'
HEADER='<b> Fancy API </b>'
BOTTOM='This material is protected under international copyright laws. Do not copy.<p>Copyright &copy; 2013 Generator Productions. All rights reserved.'
SRCDIR='../src/api/'
DSTDIR='./'

javadoc -sourcepath $SRCDIR -d $DSTDIR -use -splitIndex -windowtitle $WINDOWTITLE -doctitle $DOCTITLE -header $HEADER -bottom $BOTTOM com.generator.electricity
```

When I execute the script I get these errors:

```
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "size="-2">TM</font></sup>"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "Productions""
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "</b>"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "laws."
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "copy.<p>Copyright"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "&copy;"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "2013"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "Productions."
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "reserved."
Loading source files for package Fancy...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package Fancy
Loading source files for package Documentation...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package Documentation
Loading source files for package Fancy...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package Fancy
Loading source files for package API...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package API
Loading source files for package material...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package material
Loading source files for package is...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package is
Loading source files for package protected...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package protected
Loading source files for package under...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package under
Loading source files for package international...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package international
Loading source files for package copyright...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package copyright
Loading source files for package Do...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package Do
Loading source files for package not...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package not
Loading source files for package Generator...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package Generator
Loading source files for package All...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package All
Loading source files for package rights...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package rights
Loading source files for package com.generator.electricity...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package com.generator.electricity
9 errors
```

Any suggestion how can I get this thing done?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html

Comment: @phs How is that helping? Is it an old classic RTFM? If you wanted to help you would probably spare a couple of words as well.

Comment: well, I found that I can solve the problem if I modify the line like this: javadoc -sourcepath "$SRCDIR" -d "$DSTDIR" -use -splitIndex -windowtitle "$WINDOWTITLE" -doctitle "$DOCTITLE" -header "$HEADER" -bottom "$BOTTOM" com.generator.electricity
But I wold prefer a solution that do something to variables so that they are already suitable to be used in the javadoc invocation line.

Comment: @alex.veprik there you have your solution with "" escaping the variables when using them. what is wrong with that? alternatively add backslashes into your string variable, but that does not improve the situation at all.

Comment: @alex.veprik double-quotes are the best way to solve this; there is nothing you can put in the variables that'll do what you want. See [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/616351/spaces-in-linux-environmental-variables/616410#616410) for more details and a couple of other options (that you probably don't want to use).

Answer (score 0):

> how can I get this thing done?

In shell to properly pass variables in programs you have to quote variable expansions, to disable word splitting and filename expansion.

```
javadoc -sourcepath "$SRCDIR" -d "$DSTDIR" -use -splitIndex -windowtitle "$WINDOWTITLE" -doctitle $DOCTITLE -header "$HEADER" -bottom "$BOTTOM" com.generator.electricity
```

Remember to check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net